# Question about initial value problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This seems like it should be something simple.

While solving some HW problems I ran across this:

$dy/dx = ({1-2x})/y$

which I separated and integrated:

$\int{Ydy} = \int{1-2x}dx$

$y^2/2= x-x^2 + c$

$y^2=2(x-x^2+c)$

$y=\sqrt{2(x-x^2+c)}$

$y=\sqrt{2x-2x^2+2c}$

I was given $y(1)=-2$ and asked to solve. So i did this:

$-2=\sqrt{2(1)-2(1^2)+2c}$

$-2=\sqrt{2-2+2c}$

$-2=\sqrt{2c}$

So, I assumed c must be some complex number? However, the final solution given by the book pops a negative sign into the equation and just has $c=2$, so the solution looks like this:

$y=-\sqrt{2x-2x^2+2c}$

where $c=2$

$y=-\sqrt{2x-2x^2+4}$

which is obviously a true statement. I'm just confused where the negative sign on the right side of the equation came from.  I'm sure its some silly algebra thing I keep overlooking.

Comment: Note that $y^2=2(x-x^2+c)\implies y=\sqrt{2(x-x^2+c)}\lor y=-\sqrt{2(x-x^2+c)}$. You don't know which one holds at first. You actually proved the first one doesn't hold for that particular IVP.

Comment: Can you really do the separation? I mean - I really don't see how you did it. You are going to get
$$y\mathrm{d}y=(y-2x)\mathrm{d}x$$
and I don't think this is separable problem

Comment: How so? I don't see where your y is coming from in "(y-2x)"

Comment: I suspect that there is a missing pair of brackets (or parentheses if you will) in the differential equation: shouldn't it be $\frac{dy}{dx}=(1-2x)/y$?

Comment: Aha! Correct, Shane.  I edited the problem and added the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that in general if $y^2=a$, then either $y=\sqrt{a}$ or $y=-\sqrt{a}$. You've basically overlooked the second possibility in your solution above when you deduce that $y=\sqrt{2(x-x^2+c)}$; the negative square root is the other possibility, and this gives rise to the genuine solution of the IVP.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac {y^2}{2} = -x^2+x+c \iff y=-\sqrt2 \sqrt{-x^2+x+c}$$ or $$y=\sqrt2 \sqrt{-x^2+x+c}$$
The first one when solved for the initial condition gives $c=2$ while the second one has no solution, thus can't satisfy the initial condition, ergo no solution exists. So you're left with only $$y=-\sqrt2 \sqrt{-x^2+x+2}$$